# Deadlock while bulk inserts in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

> PG::TRDeadlockDetected: ERROR: deadlock detected\nDETAIL: Process 5449
>   waits for ShareLock on transaction 1712360; blocked by process
>   1325.\nProcess 1325 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1712346; blocked by process 5449.\nHINT: See server log for query
>   details.\nCONTEXT: while inserting index tuple (663142,4) in relation
>   "contacts"\n:

Getting deadlock while performing concurrent bulk inserts on table Contact.
This table also has unique constraint on column phone. 
,Also there are parallel reads on this table.

Query on which deadlock  occurs is

```
INSERT INTO contacts (phone, name, email, external_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{values} ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

where values is list  of tuples(phone, name, email, external_id, created_at, updated_at) of size 300 to 400.
```

Primary key of this table is uuid and default value is `gen_random_uuid()`

Comment: You can follow this http://www.moioli.net/progetti/postgres-deadlocks-debugging-guidelines/ steps to determine the root cause of a deadlock.

Comment: Could be concurrent DML statements that either affect the table itself or a second table to which `contacts` has a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Check this out: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194756/deadlock-with-multi-row-inserts-despite-on-conflict-do-nothing